# rails factory girl getting "Email has already been taken"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

This is my factory girl code, and every time I try to generate a review, it's telling me that "Email has already been taken", i've reset my databases, set the transition in spec_helper to true, but still haven't solved the problem. I'm new to this, am I using the association wrong? Thanks!

```
Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.name                  "Testing User"
  user.email                 "test@example.com"
  user.password              "foobar"
  user.password_confirmation "foobar"
end

Factory.define :course do |course|
  course.title "course"
  course.link "www.umn.edu"
  course.sections 21
  course.description "test course description"
  course.association :user
end

Factory.define :review do |review|
  review.title "Test Review"
  review.content "Test review content"
  review.association :user
  review.association :course
end
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use a sequence to prevent the creation of user objects with the same email, since you must have a validation for the uniqueness of emails in your User model.

```
Factory.sequence :email do |n|
  “test#{n}@example.com”
end

Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.name "Testing User"
  user.email { Factory.next(:email) }
  user.password "foobar"
  user.password_confirmation "foobar"
end
```

You can read more in the [Factory Girl documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki/Usage).

Answer (score 36):

I know this is a pretty old question, but the accepted answer is out of date, so I figured I should post the new way of doing this.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence :email do |n|
    "email#{n}@factory.com"
  end

  factory :user do
    email
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"
  end
end
```

Source: [Documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#sequences)

It's quite a bit simpler, which is nice.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the above answers you could add `gem 'faker'` to your Gemfile and it will provide unique emails.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :admin do
    association :band
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password "asdfasdf"
    password_confirmation "asdfasdf"
  end
end
```

Comment: Here the important detail is to put the Faker generator into brackets`{ }` like in the example `email { Faker::Internet.email }` as it will not work without them and will raise the same error.

Answer (score 5):

`sequence` gives really unique email and `Faker` gives random password.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence :email do |n|
    "user#{n}@test.com"
  end

  factory :user do
    email
    password { Faker::Internet.password(min_length: 8, max_length:20) }
    password_confirmation { "#{password}" }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to add a sequence
2. (optional) If you are often executing the factory in rails console you can add some randomness `Random.hex(4)` otherwise you will run into the same problem.

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) do |index|
      "test_#{Random.hex(4)}#{index}@fake-domain.xyx"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the `password_confirmation` field wasn't working for me. What worked was this:

```rb
FactoryBot.define do

  sequence :email do |n|
    "user#{n}@test.com"
  end

  factory :user do
    email
    password { Faker::Internet.password(min_length: 8, max_length:20) }
    confirmed_at { Time.current } # <---- This worked for me
  end
end
```

Note that if you're not using Faker, you can have something as simple as `password { "password" } instead of that line.